# вызов функции Python (библиотека requests)

Tags: python, requests

Всем привет! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в вызове функций на Python.
у меня есть скрипт, по сути набор функций и, если правильно выражаюсь, результат выполнения одной функции влияет на выполнение другой.
первая функция - это получение токена

```
def get_token():
    url = 'https://stata.com/api/sign_in'

    data = {"login":"avokado","password":"green"}',
    }

    response = requests.post(url, data=data)
    
    token = response.json()

    token = token['access_token']
    
    return token
```

дальше я собираю url адрес, по которому будут доступны данные

```
def get_url(token):
    base_url = 'https://api.stata.com/access_token='
    
    url = [
        base_url,
        token,
    ] 
    
    url = ''.join(url)
  
    return url
```

при вызове первой функции

```
get_token()
```

я получаю token (70ddf80a4528436fe28223bbahe68fe150d30309)
а при вызове второй функции get_url(token) я получаю адрес:
'https://api.stata.com/access_token=**token**'
если я правильно понимаю результат вызова второй функции должен быть
'https://api.stata.com/access_token=70ddf80a4528436fe28223bbahe68fe150d30309'
???

ну и получается третья функция

```
def get_data(url):
    
    res = requests.get(url=url)
    data = res.json()

    return data
```

с ней также возникает вопрос, точно понимаю, что вот так не сработает

```
get_data(url)
```

Благодарю за любую помощь, ответы, направление на ресурсы

Comment: Почему вы решили 'что вот так не сработает get_data(url)'?

Comment: Вызывает сомнение формат url. Он точно должен быть `https://api.stata.com/access_token=873457384` а не `https://api.stata.com?access_token=23789237498237` или, что наиболее вероятно, `https://api.stata.com/7849738472394273`?

Comment: Приветствую вас, Сергей) это вызывает ошибку Invalid URL 'url': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://url?

Comment: Namerek, да точно, исходя из документации по моему сайту, прогоняю код без функций - все работает

Comment: Тогда распечатайте результат возвращаемый функцией и сравните с рабочим вариантом

Comment: Еще один вопрос, это ничего, что у Вас при запросе токена в url доменная зона не указана? `'https://stata/api/sign_in'` Там у вас вообще бардак, но все-же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в 2‑х словах, то вот так как-то.
datetime использовал для демонстрации возможностей так сказать.

Сборку url через `Url` сделал для наглядности. Мне, к примеру так удобней с динамическим набором параметров работать. Тем более когда их много

```
from datetime import datetime
from urllib3.util import Url
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests

data = {"login":"avokado","password":"green"}

response = requests.get(
    'https://api.some_site.com/auth',
    data=data
)

# token = 'ad721950597208b6e79e2089a01e41fc0b9707b6'
token = response.json(object_hook=lambda x: x.get('access_token'))

group_id = '6030d723e9fa83692542a70d'

date_start = datetime(2022, 5, 10, 21, 0, 0)
date_end = datetime(2022, 5, 14, 21, 0, 0)


url = Url(
    scheme='https',
    host='api.some_site.com',
    path=f'/api/nr/group/{group_id}/stats',
    query=urlencode(
        {
            'api_version': '1.1',
            'access_token': token,
            # 'date_end': '2022-05-14T21:00:00.000Z',
            # 'date_start': '2022-05-10T21:00:00.000Z',
            'date_end': date_end.isoformat(),
            'date_start': date_start.isoformat(),
            'granularity': 'day'
        },
        safe=':'
    )
)
response = requests.get(url)
```

> Если дату через isoformat не схвает, отформатируйте через strftime

```
# Ну или просто 
response = requests.get(
    f'https://api.some_site.com/api/nr/group/{group_id}/stats',
    params={
        'api_version': '1.1',
        'access_token': token,
        # 'date_end': '2022-05-14T21:00:00.000Z',
        # 'date_start': '2022-05-10T21:00:00.000Z',
        'date_end': date_end.isoformat(),
        'date_start': date_start.isoformat(),
        'granularity': 'day'
    }
)
```